# How to declare an iterator with items that live as long as the iterator, not the container?

Tags: rust

First the error message:

```
[INFO]: Checking for the Wasm target...
[INFO]: Compiling to Wasm...
   Compiling snakelib v0.1.0 (/home/jeff/gitrepos/code/code/pdfsnake/firebase/webapp/wasm)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> pdfsnake/firebase/webapp/wasm/src/i16word_wasm.rs:214:13
    |
207 | impl<'a> Iterator for I16WordIterMut<'a> {
    |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
210 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
214 |             Some(n)
    |             ^^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`

error: could not compile `snakelib` (lib) due to previous error
Error: Compiling your crate to WebAssembly failed
Caused by: failed to execute `cargo build`: exited with exit status: 101
  full command: "cargo" "build" "--lib" "--release" "--target" "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
```

And the code:

```
use core::arch::wasm32;

const I16_COUNT: usize = 8;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct I16Word {
    pub w: wasm32::v128
}


impl From<&mut I16Word> for [i16; I16_COUNT] {
    fn from(w: &mut I16Word) -> [i16; I16_COUNT] {
        [
            wasm32::i16x8_extract_lane::<0>(w.w),
            wasm32::i16x8_extract_lane::<1>(w.w),
            wasm32::i16x8_extract_lane::<2>(w.w),
            wasm32::i16x8_extract_lane::<3>(w.w),
            wasm32::i16x8_extract_lane::<4>(w.w),
            wasm32::i16x8_extract_lane::<5>(w.w),
            wasm32::i16x8_extract_lane::<6>(w.w),
            wasm32::i16x8_extract_lane::<7>(w.w)
        ]
    }
}

impl I16Word {
    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> I16WordIterMut {
        let slice: [i16; I16_COUNT] = self.into();
        I16WordIterMut { word: slice, i16word: self, index: 0 }
    }

}

pub struct I16WordIterMut<'a> {
    word: [i16; I16_COUNT],
    i16word: &'a mut I16Word,
    index: usize
}

impl<'a> Iterator for I16WordIterMut<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut i16;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index < I16_COUNT {
            let n = &mut self.word[self.index];
            self.index += 1;
            Some(n)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Drop for I16WordIterMut<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        *self.i16word = (&self.word).into();
    }
}
```

I think I understand the error message, but I can't figure out a fix or a workaround.

The underlying data structure, a `wasm32::v128`, provides no way for me to get a `&mut i16`, So I keep a copy in the iterator.  Because I keep a mutable reference to the container, nothing else can read or write to the container, so I should be safe to copy the content back to the container when the iterator is dropped.

**Update: After adopting Chayim's answer**

The code compiles, but the code that calls it doesn't.

```
[INFO]: Checking for the Wasm target...
[INFO]: Compiling to Wasm...
   Compiling snakelib v0.1.0 (/home/jeff/gitrepos/code/code/pdfsnake/firebase/webapp/wasm)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> pdfsnake/firebase/webapp/wasm/src/i16vec.rs:161:26
    |
161 |                 self.j = self.i.next().map(|w| w.iter_mut());
    |                 ------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Option<IterMut<'_, i16>>`, found `Option<I16WordIterMut<'_>>`
    |                 |
    |                 expected due to the type of this binding
    |
    = note: expected enum `std::option::Option<std::slice::IterMut<'a, i16>>`
               found enum `std::option::Option<I16WordIterMut<'_>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `snakelib` (lib) due to previous error
Error: Compiling your crate to WebAssembly failed
Caused by: failed to execute `cargo build`: exited with exit status: 101
  full command: "cargo" "build" "--lib" "--release" "--target" "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
```

```
pub struct I16VecIterMut<'a> {
    i: std::slice::IterMut<'a, I16Word>,
    j: Option<std::slice::IterMut<'a, i16>>,
    remaining: usize
}

impl<'a> Iterator for I16VecIterMut<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut i16;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.remaining < 1 {
            return None;
        }
        self.remaining -= 1;
        for _ in 0..2 {
            if self.j.is_none() {
                self.j = self.i.next().map(|w| w.iter_mut());
            }
            match self.j {
                Some(ref mut j) => match j.next() {
                    Some(n) => return Some(n),
                    None => {
                        self.j = None;
                    }   
                },
                None => return None
            }
        }
        panic!("I16VecIterMut::next() loop error")
    }
}
```

Stepping out of the weeds for a moment, the goal I want to achieve is to iterate over a `Vec<v128>` as if it were a `Vec<i16>`.  I want to iterate over the i16s packed into the v128s.

Comment: @PitaJ I will argue it is not even a duplicate (of this at least), but at least it's a very _not useful_ duplicate.

Comment: PitaJ, nope. I don't intend to store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct.

Comment: Woops, misread something. FYI your example fails to compile with a different error because you forgot to include the other `From` impl.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write an iterator that yields references to itself, because the items returned by an iterator may outlive the iterator.

However, here you don't need to: the type can just be an `IntoIterator` and return the normal array iterator. This is also more efficient, since you don't keep track of the index and you benefit from all of the optimizations of slice iterators:

```rust
pub struct I16WordIterMut<'a> {
    word: [i16; I16_COUNT],
    i16word: &'a mut I16Word,
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut I16WordIterMut<'_> {
    type IntoIter = std::slice::IterMut<'a, i16>;
    type Item = &'a mut i16;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.word.iter_mut()
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be referred to as the "lending iterator" problem.

Comment: @PitaJ I'm hesitant to refer to this as an example of lending iterator since the problem solved with lending iterators is usually the existence of items that mutably borrow overlapping parts of the iterator (the famous `windows_mut()`), but here this is not a problem since the yielded items are not overlapping, the problem is that the items may outlive the iterator. Hence, "real" lending iterators cannot be "solved" by making them `IntoIterator` instead.

Comment: I updated the question with a new compile error.

Comment: @JeffreyRennie This is a new question. Please ask a new question. And also, please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for it.

Comment: Will do. Chayim, thank you for your help

Answer (score -2):

What you really need is a trait like `BorrowedIterator<'a>` with a method `next(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>` to let you give the lifetime `&'a` to `Self::Item`. In the absence of such a trait, you can simply write the method you'd use (or the trait itself, but that seems like overkill):

```rust
impl<'a> I16WordIterMut<'a> {
    fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a mut i16> {
        if self.index < I16_COUNT {
            let n = &mut self.word[self.index];
            self.index += 1;
            Some(n)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

There isn't any native syntax for this like there is for `for` loops, so you'll have to write `while let Some(x) = i16_iter_mut.next() {...}`

Comment: `&'a mut Thing<'a>` is always wrong. This will make it impossible to actually use the iterator. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=591820d8ed211bb91416bae93cff1da6.